# Firefox web extension - read local file (last downloaded file)

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest, filereader

Im creating a web extension and porting from XUL. I used to be able to easily read files with

```
  var dJsm = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm").Downloads;
  var tJsm = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm").Task;
  var fuJsm = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm").FileUtils;
  var nsiPromptService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPromptService);

  ....

  NetUtil.asyncFetch(file, function(inputStream, status) {
           if (!Components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
            return;
           }
            var data =  NetUtil.readInputStreamToString(inputStream, inputStream.available());
            var data = window.btoa(data);
            var encoded_data_to_send_via_xmlhttp = encodeURIComponent(data);
            ...
  });
```

This above will be deprecated.

I can use the downloads.download() to know what was the last download but I can NOT read the file and then get the equivalent for encoded_data_to_send_via_xmlhttp

Also in Firefox 57 onwards, means that I have to try to fake a user action by a button click or something, or upload a file.

```
  Access to file:// URLs or reading files without any explicit user input
```

isnt there an easy way to read the last downloaded file?

Comment: Reading the file from a url e.g. '/Downloads/random.txt' - this is what has to be read and then posted

Comment: See info in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Working_with_files) as well as the linked code examples.

Comment: Doesnt help. I cant read the file anyway

Comment: It is possible to read the downloaded url via XMLHttp set this to blob, then use FileReader.readAsDataURL() to read the blob. But I dont want to do this. Sometimes the URL is blocked so that the download exists in the local storage.

Comment: Why not send the URL from the download item object to the server instead and then invoke a transfer from URL to server there?

Comment: Thats because the user has logged into a site and sharing the session from the client to the server isnt possible, IP restrictions etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WebExtension API won't allow extensions to read local files anymore. You could let the extension get CORS privilege and read the content directly from the URL via `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()` as blob and store directly to IndexedDB or memory, then encode and send to server. This comes with [many restrictions and limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy) such as to which origin you can read from and so forth.

Also, this would add potentially many unneeded steps. If the purpose is, as it seem to be in the question at the moment, to share the downloaded file with a server, I would instead suggest that you obtain the last [`DownloadItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/DownloadItem) object, extract the URL (`.url`) from that object and send the *URL* back to server.

This way the server can load directly from that URL (and encode it on server if needed). The network load will be about the same (a little less actually since there is no Base64 encoding involved which adds 33% to the size), and much less load on the client. The server would read the data as a binary/byte data stream; about the same as if the data was sent directly from the extension.

To obtain the last downloaded file you would do the following from a privileged script:

```
browser.downloads.search({
  limit: 1,
  orderBy: ["-startTime"]
})
.then(getLastDownload);

function getLastDownload(downloads) {
  if (downloads.length) {
    var url = downloads[0].url;
    // ... send url to the server and let server fetch the data from it directly
  }
}
```

Comment: To be fair, I already indicated this was possible in the earlier comments, it doesnt seem to get round the solution.

Comment: I have looked at native messaging and running a small app to do the grunt work for me, its not ideal but given that I cant "read" any downloaded file due to the MDN guidelines in FF for security.  Its possible to install an app alongside the web extension to take parameters from the download API and then read the file locally and post this to the server

Comment: Also the last browser.downloads.search doesnt actually present the last download 100% of the time. If a download is in progress I need to wait for this to finish then send this to the server so I opted to use an eventListener instead

Comment: I have solved it using the earlier approach to read the downloaded url via XMLHttp set this to blob, then use FileReader.readAsDataURL() to read the blob then send this to the server encoded as Base64, just that my download can be triggered twice (once from the user clicking, then from this process of listening to the download and then refetching it and sending it....cumbersome...

Answer (score 2):

According to [this support mozilla question](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963224).

> (2) Local file security
>
> Firefox limits access from pages on web servers to pages on local disk or UNC paths.  [...]).

Which solution ?

- Use [local-filesystem-links firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links) (not tested)

and/or

- run a small local webserver on client side, supposing server was run with sufficient privileges, you may finally access any local content via http:// (but still cannot with file:///)